# Calling a sub from another forms gives different results

Tags: vb.net, forms, sockets, nullreferenceexception, public

I'm having a trouble with VB.NET:

I've got 3 different Forms (Public Class): mainForm, plotForm and tradeForm.

Both plotForm and tradeForm call a sub which is part of mainForm, called SendHost:

```
Public Class mainForm
    Public Sub SendHost(Text As String)
        Dim OutData() As Byte = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Text)
        Client.BeginSend(OutData, 0, OutData.Length, SocketFlags.None, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnSend), Client)
    End Sub
End Class
```

When calling from plotForm, there's no problem at all:

```
Public Class plotForm
    Private Sub btnBuy_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBuy.Click
        mainForm.SendHost("GBuy§" & Prop.PositionID)
        ''' Another code here....    
    End Sub
End Class
```

However, when the same sub is called from another sub called Trade, there is a problem:

```
Public Class tradeForm
    Private Sub Trade(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTrade.Click
        btnTrade.Enabled = False
        mainForm.SendHost("GATS§" & ID)
        'More code here...
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

This will start the sub in mainForm, but Visual Studio tells me that "Client" is Null, giving me a NullReferenceExpection. This doesn't happen with btnBuy_Click. I dont understand this, and any hints to a solution are very welcome! Thank you! Feel free to ask anything.

plotForm and tradeForm are started like (in mainForm, different subs):

```
Dim TradeW As New Trade
TradeW.ShowDialog(Me)
```

and:

```
Dim plotbox As New PlotBox
plotbox.ShowDialog(Me)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You hint is, "where is `Client` instantiated?"

Comment: Client is part of mainForm,
Initialized at beginging of it.
 Dim Client As Socket
It's connected to remote host and begins sending data at the SendHost sub.

Comment: Clearly `Client` isn't being instantiated, but you haven't posted the code that shows how it is so we can't help. You need a [mcve].

Comment: Also both of those subs are ran only after the connection is made to the server via the same client (nothing changed)

Comment: Here's full mainForm: http://paste.ofcode.org/HAFU4UKk25ES5mmHNDk8FH
Here's full plotForm: http://paste.ofcode.org/DpVTqqXPncaBrT7TFYqWjW
Here's full tradeForm: http://paste.ofcode.org/g5Q5hcNpG2nqJzaiqmxfnL

Hopefully this gives us a clue

Comment: There appears to be only one place in the `mainForm` that `Client` is instantiated. And it is done in button click event. So now we need to find out all the places that `mainForm` is instantiated. Or are you using the default instance?

Comment: Yes I believe so. Im so sorry for disturbing you this much, I really appreciate your help! :D If this helps, heres the whole project here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoMbdmwE9zfGdiyXV3GThgg74kg

Comment: Yeah, your problem is that you're using the default instance of your main form. You need to explicitly declare and pass the reference to `mainForm` around the place.

Comment: You're also doing some weird stuff like `Dim tradew As New Trade With {.IncomingTrade = False, .PlotList = PlotList, .PlayerList = PlayerList, .ImHost = ImHost}`. That just makes you expose more stuff than you need. You should incorporate that stuff into the constructor to allow the components to be encapsulated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem was that somewhere you were picking up the wrong (or new instance) of `mainForm`. You're using the shared instance of `mainForm` which is a wholly bad idea. I don't know why that feature was ever introduced to VB.NET - it just leads to bugs like this.

I ended up downloading your project and basically manually renamed the class `mainForm` to `mainFormClass` and then introduced this code throughout your classes until your project compiled:

```
Dim mainForm As mainFormClass

Public Sub New(mainForm As mainFormClass)

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    Me.mainForm = mainForm

End Sub
```

I had to then change the instantiation of each form to be like `Dim propW As New PlotBox(Me.mainForm)` or `Dim plotbox As New PlotBox(Me)` depending where the class was made.

I got it all to compile, but I couldn't determine if your bug was resolved, but I assume that it was.